# What should I do when encircled by competitors?

Tags: railroad-tycoon, railroad-tycoon-deluxe

Situation A: I am facing a mighty competitor who has built a transcontinental railroad from east to west. Such a railroad blocks my expansion plans from north to south, because rail lines cannot cross.

Situation B: In a dense region with lots of cities, I have a rail line between two cities. However, I am quickly surrounded by other railroads servicing other nearby cities, and all these competitor rail lines have encircled me. It is impossible to expand.

If I am facing any of the situations above, how can I expand?